# WordPress wp-login.php file changes automatically

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am having trouble with my WordPress site for a few weeks. I have a WordPress site installed in shared hosting with the latest version of WordPress.
I recurringly have to change wp-login.php in every few hours as it gets changed every time. When I change the file, it works for a few hours but again shows error after a few hours. Basically I get 2 types of error;

1. wp-login.php gets downloaded while visiting mydomain/wp-admin.
2. Showing code error.

These codes are added automatically;

```
setcookie("whatsup","whatsupman",time()+3600*24*365);
setcookie("whatsup","whatsupman",time()+3600*24*365);
setcookie("whatsup","whatsupman",time()+3600*24*365);
setcookie("whatsup","whatsupman",time()+3600*24*365);
setcookie("whatsup","whatsupman",time()+3600*24*365);
setcookie("whatsup","whatsupman",time()+3600*24*365);
setcookie("whatsup","whatsupman",time()+3600*24*365);
setcookie("whatsup","whatsupman",time()+3600*24*365);
setcookie("whatsup","whatsupman",time()+3600*24*365);
setcookie("whatsup","whatsupman",time()+3600*24*365);
setcookie("whatsup","whatsupman",time()+3600*24*365);
setcookie("whatsup","whatsupman",time()+3600*24*365);
setcookie("whatsup","whatsupman",time()+3600*24*365);
setcookie("whatsup","whatsupman",time()+3600*24*365);
setcookie("whatsup","whatsupman",time()+3600*24*365);
setcookie("whatsup","whatsupman",time()+3600*24*365);
setcookie("whatsup","whatsupman",time()+3600*24*365);
setcookie("whatsup","whatsupman",time()+3600*24*365);
setcookie("whatsup","whatsupman",time()+3600*24*365);
setcookie("whatsup","whatsupman",time()+3600*24*365);
setcookie("whatsup","whatsupman",time()+3600*24*365);
setcookie("whatsup","whatsupman",time()+3600*24*365);
setcookie("whatsup","whatsupman",time()+3600*24*365);
setcookie("whatsup","whatsupman",time()+3600*24*365);
setcookie("whatsup","whatsupman",time()+3600*24*365);
setcookie("whatsup","whatsupman",time()+3600*24*365);
```

Comment: And what's your question about this? Looks like you've got hacked

Comment: For example, https://blog.sucuri.net/2020/04/wordpress-admin-login-stealer.html references that cookie

Comment: Any idea to troubleshoot this problem and remove malware from site?